# SpringBoot @MockBean and @WebMvcTest does not work

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, springrunner

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    //Below userService implementation
    @PostMapping(value = "/addNewUser", consumes = "application/json")
    public void addNewUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
        userService.addNewUser(newUser);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/findUserById/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public User findUserById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return userService.findUserById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/findUserByName/{name}", produces = "application/json")
    public User findUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        return userService.findUserByName(name);
    }
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Transactional
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void addNewUser(User newUser) {
        userRepository.save(newUser);
    }
```

Repository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findUserByName(String name);

    Optional<User>  findUserBySurname(String surname);
}
```

ControllerTest.java

```
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

//    @MockBean
//    private UserService userService;
//
//    @MockBean
//    private BookService bookService;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @Mock
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }
}
```

Above configuration works ok, but below not.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;

//    @Mock
//    private UserService userService;
//
//    @Mock
//    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }
}
```

and i get this error

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
>   configuration.
>
> 2018-11-26 21:58:32.343 ERROR 7385 --- [           main]
>   o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
>   allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@5c7bfdc1]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.webservices.example.librarydatabaseservice.controller.ControllerTest@74f827ad]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:99)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]    at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   ~[junit-rt.jar:na]    at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   ~[junit-rt.jar:na]    at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   ~[junit-rt.jar:na]    at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   ~[junit-rt.jar:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'bookRepository': Cannot create inner bean
>   '(inner bean)#3f362135' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3f362135': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
>   ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   ~[spring-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]    ... 25 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3f362135': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:660)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:478)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   ... 43 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1212)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]   ... 51 common frames
>   omitted

It says that there is a problem with entityFactoryManager, but in 1 mock way it works and in another not...

Full code [Github repo](https://github.com/pietrasikk/library-database-service)

I'm using SpringBoot in version: **2.1.0.RELEASE**

Comment: To use Controller into ControllerTest, try to use @InjectMocks then before you use MockMvc.perform(...) try to stu you repository methods by using when(repository.add(any())).thenReturn(example); and so and so, is that clear or you want an example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your test is loading up JPA with a `entityManagerFactory` bean. In your main application class, I think you have written `@EnableJpaRepositories`, which isn't needed if you have your repository under your main application's base package. Remove this annotation since your test class should only be meant for testing the web layer.

Comment: This solved my issue. I spent almost a day searching for answers. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try adding a configuration class to the project like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.webservices.example.librarydatabaseservice.repository")
public class RepositoryConfiguration {
}
```

The problem has nothing to do with your test. It's a problem Spring has starting and loading the services. In Mockito version of the test you don't require it to load all classes and mock the service/repository, so that masks the problem. In the other version of the test the SpringRunner needs to load your applicationContext, which fails because of the missing JPA configuration.

Comment: I wanted to avoid loading spring context so I did not use SprintBootTest. I wanted to create just quick controller test with mock, but as you said that I have to add this configuration in SpringRunner.class to spring context loads so maybe the better option is just use SprintBootTest and don't create any configuration file.